# Intellij IDEA and Gradle Wrapper on Windows / Linux

Tags: linux, windows, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I don't want to download the wrapper from the internet -- that is, the DistributionUrl I set is local. I have an absolute path (can't be relative) for both Windows and Linux, but they're slightly different.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can set up Gradle/IDEA in such a way that my wrapper will work for both platforms?

Can I set up two wrappers? Through IDEA?

Something that can be done with an init script? Does IDEA recognize these?

I tried creating a wrapper task with both .properties file set ups, but IDEA ignores it.

Thanks.